# Retrofit 2 image upload success but image uploads as corrupted file

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

So heres the thing, the file is successfully uploaded as a "photo.png" but when i open the photo from the browser the photo is corrupted. When i download the photo to open it locally in my computer, the photo is corrupted.

No idea why.

Heres the retrofit endpoint:

```
@Multipart
@POST("alerts/{alertId}/photo/")
Call<Object> uploadPhotoStill(@Header("Authorization") String credentials, @Path("alertId") int alertId,
                              @Part("photo\"; filename=\"picture_taken.jpeg\" ") RequestBody photo);
```

Here is how i am using it: i am grabbing the byte array that comes back from taking a picture with the camera object.

```
private void initCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);

        camera.setParameters(params);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when image data is available after a picture is taken.
 * The format of the data depends on the context of the callback
 * and {@link Camera.Parameters} settings.
 *
 * @param data   a byte array of the picture data
 * @param camera the Camera service object
 */
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken() called with: " + "data = [" + Arrays.toString(data) + "], camera = [" + camera + "]");
    handleTakenStill(data);
}

private void handleTakenStill(byte[] data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleTakenStill() was called");

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), data);

    havenApi.uploadPhotoStill(Utils.encodeUserCredentials(), getCurrentAlert().getId(), requestBody).enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Object> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "handleTakenStill.onResponse success: " + response.body().toString());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "handleTakenStill.onResponse error: " + response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Utils.logOnFailureRequest(TAG, t);
        }
    });
}
```

The success is always called after uploading the photo. But the photo always uploads corrupted and i have no idea why.

Comment: Is the image in PNG format?

Comment: @TheSunny the image is just a byteArray grabbed from the onPictureTaken method

Comment: So which format is the image? The comment above the method onPictureTaken states that the format of the data depends on parameters passed in. You should check this out and see if that may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @TheSunny thats not the problem. Changed it all to jpeg to be sure and still same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to get this working with retrofit. But i was able to do it with OkHttp.

If you are wondering how here is the solution:

```
/**
 * Called when image data is available after a picture is taken.
 * The format of the data depends on the context of the callback
 * and {@link Camera.Parameters} settings.
 *
 * @param data   a byte array of the picture data
 * @param camera the Camera service object
 */
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken() called with: " + "data = [" + Arrays.toString(data) + "], camera = [" + camera + "]");
    handleTakenStill(data);
}

private void handleTakenStill(byte[] data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleTakenStill() was called");

    Observable.create(uploadPhoto(data))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<com.squareup.okhttp.Response>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted() was called");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Utils.logOnFailureRequest(TAG, e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(com.squareup.okhttp.Response response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "handleTakenStill.onResponse success: " + response.body().toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "handleTakenStill.onResponse error: " + response.message());
                    }
                }
            });
}

@NonNull
private Observable.OnSubscribe<com.squareup.okhttp.Response> uploadPhoto(final byte[] data) {
    return new Observable.OnSubscribe<com.squareup.okhttp.Response>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super com.squareup.okhttp.Response> subscriber) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("camera", "picture_taken.jpg", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), data))
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
                    .addHeader("authorization", Utils.encodeUserCredentials())
                    .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .build();

            try {
                com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                subscriber.onNext(response);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    subscriber.onError(new Exception("Error uploading photo"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. instead of using a MultiPart form, I used a simple RequestBody for the image data which works for me. I'm using Kotlin in an Android project.

My Retrofit API:

```
interface FilesApi {
    @PUT("/files/attachments/{parentId}")
    fun uploadAttachment(
        @Path("parentId") parentId: String,
        @Header("Content-Type") contentType: String,
        @Header("Name") name: String,
        @Header("Description") description: String?,
        @Body image: RequestBody
    ): Single<Response<FileUploadResponse>>
}
```

Creating the request object:

the imageData var is a ByteArray

```
val requestFile = imageData.toRequestBody(contentType.toMediaTypeOrNull(), 0, imageData.size)

return filesApi.uploadAttachment(parentId, contentType, name, description, requestFile)
            .map { response ->
                response.code()
                response.errorBody()
                response.body()?.Result
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Check the Photo type as said in comments. Sometimes swith to JPG format solve problem.

2) Try to put as parameters to RequestBody just file, or path to file (Another constructor of RequestBode object)

I use code below without problem, But i sending file as Form Data:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/api/tour/upload")
    Call<MainFileModel> uploadTourFiles(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);


    File mainFile = new File(fileLoad.getFile());
    Map params = new Map<>();
    params.put("file\"; filename=\"" + mainFile.getName(),
      RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),                                 mainFile));; 


//And Make call here!
```